# Python finite-state machines with module `pysm`

Tags: python, state-machine

Why doesn't this code work as it obviously should?

The machine below has two states: `idle` and `travelling`, and a transition between the two named `go`. I use `register_handlers` to attach to this transition `on_enter` and `on_go` handlers. I expected the result of this code to be two prints, one of each handler. For some reason it seems only the on_enter handler is executed.

```
import pysm

machine = pysm.pysm.StateMachine('ship')

idle = pysm.pysm.State('idle')

class TravellingState(pysm.pysm.State):
    def on_go(self, state, event):
        print("on_go function called")

    def on_enter(self, state, event):
        print("on_enter function called")

    def register_handlers(self):
        self.handlers = {
            'enter': self.on_enter,
            'go': self.on_go, # doesnt work?
        }

travelling = TravellingState('travelling')

machine.add_state(idle, initial=True)
machine.add_state(travelling)

machine.add_transition(from_state=idle, to_state=travelling, events=['go'])

machine.initialize()

machine.dispatch(pysm.pysm.Event('go', cargo={'target':(1,1)}))
```

Comment: Why are you expecting two prints?  You've dispatched only one event.  Only one handler has executed.

Comment: There's two handlers that match: the one on_enter one that matchs whenever a state is entered, and the on_go which matchs the event type. Put differently, a case that we have the same expectation about: if you comment out the line `'enter': self.on_enter` we both would still be expecting one print, right? Nope, no match happens in that case.

Comment: Compare with the example here http://pysm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysm_module.html#pysm.pysm.State

Comment: Thanks.  I see my understanding flaws.

Answer (score 0):

`go` is an event `travelling` state will handle.
But you are initially in the `idle` state. It ignores the `go` event.

You've created a transition from `idle` to `travelling` on the `go` event. So basically what you're seeing is the transition from `idle` to `travelling` and therefore the `enter` handler in the `Travelling` instance is called.

If you want to get `go` handled in the `idle` state, specify the handler in the `idle` instance:

```
def on_go(state, event):
    print('on_go from idle')

idle = pysm.pysm.State('idle')
idle.handlers = {'go': on_go}
```

And then calling

```
machine.dispatch(pysm.pysm.Event('go', cargo={'target':(1,1)}))
```

Calls the `on_go` handler in the `idle` state.

**also**

Preserving your code, if you call the `go` event once again (being already in the `travelling` state), you'll get your handler called.

```
machine.dispatch(pysm.pysm.Event('go', cargo={'target':(1,1)}))
```

And the full working example:

```
import pysm

machine = pysm.pysm.StateMachine('ship')

def on_go(state, event):
    print('on_go from idle')

idle = pysm.pysm.State('idle')
idle.handlers = {'go': on_go}


class TravellingState(pysm.pysm.State):
    def on_go(self, state, event):
        print("on_go from travelling")

    def on_enter(self, state, event):
        print("on_enter from travelling")

    def register_handlers(self):
        self.handlers = {
            'enter': self.on_enter,
            'go': self.on_go,
        }

travelling = TravellingState('travelling')

machine.add_state(idle, initial=True)
machine.add_state(travelling)

machine.add_transition(from_state=idle, to_state=travelling, events=['go'])

machine.initialize()

machine.dispatch(pysm.pysm.Event('go', cargo={'target':(1,1)}))
machine.dispatch(pysm.pysm.Event('go', cargo={'target':(1,1)}))
```

The output is, as expected:

```
# go event is dispatched
on_go from idle
# Now the transition happens
on_enter from travelling
# go is dispatched again
on_go from travelling
```